# 2D array grid in C with different characters for each coordinate

Tags: c

```
int attack_grid[10][10] = { {0} };

void drawAttackGrid()
{
    int i, j, x = 0, y = 0;
    for (i = 0; i <= 10 - 1; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 10 - 1; j++) {
            if (attack_grid[x][y] > 0)
                printf(" * ");
            else if (attack_grid[x][y] < 0)
                printf(" ~ ");
            else
                printf(" ? ");
            y++;
        }
        printf("\n");
        x++;
    }
}
```

So I am trying to fill this 10x10 array with different characters based on the value of the coordinate in other 10x10 array which is filled with zeros only(I'm gonna change those values later so that's why I need it to be general). According to my code it should print only " ? ", but there are some " * " in the output too. Can someone explain me why do i get those " * " there, please?

Comment: Aside: please change `i <= 10 - 1;` to `i < 10;` and for `j` too.

Comment: The variable `y` increases. You forgot to reset it to zero. And, why x and y was used? Why not i and j?

Comment: Your x,y pair is equivalent to your i,j pair. You should remove this redundancy.

Comment: I tried it differently at first, so that's why there are `x` and `y`... They made it just more confusing mostly for me as I see, thank you all

Comment: I try your code and in my case it print only '?'. Btw attack_grid array is init to 0 and your check every cell of it [x][y] for > or < 0 at current time it will always be == 0 and should print '?'. Sometimes it can print * because you didn't reset x,y  to 0 and check fo example 10 20 where is garbage can store

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your program has undefined behavior due to the value of `y`.

`y` gets incremented in the inner loop but never gets reset to 0 when the outer loop is repeated.

In the second run of the outer loop, the value of `y` will start at `10` instead of starting at `0`.

In the third run of the outer loop, the value of `y` will start at `20` instead of starting at `0`.

That goes on for the remaining iterations of the outer loop.

You can remove the redundant indices `x` and `y`. Use `attack_grid[i][j]` instead of `attack_grid[x][y]`